# How to stop recursive loop with `requestAnimationFrame`

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, memory-leaks, requestanimationframe

I have a class with the recursive loop function like the below:

```
class Foo {
    private isLoopOnFlg: boolean = false;

    public StartLoop() {
        this.isLoopOnFlg = true;

        this.recursiveLoopWithDelay(() => {
            // Modifying DOM objects
        }, 1000);
    }

    public StopLoop() {
        this.isLoopOnFlg = false;
    }

    // THE PROBLEM
    private recursiveLoopWithDelay(loopFn: any, delay: number) {
        let stamp = Date.now();

        // How do I stop the loop using `isLoopOnFlg`?
        function _loop() {
            if (Date.now() - stamp >= delay) {
                loopFn();
                stamp = Date.now();
            }

            window.requestAnimationFrame(_loop);
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(_loop);
    }
}
```

As you see, the function `recursiveLoopWithDelay` won't be stopped - so I've added a new private variable `isLoopOnFlg` and I want to use it to stop the recursive function - but I am not sure how to do it.  I tried to stop the function by adding a new parameter `keepLoopFlg` in the function like the below:

```
...
private recursiveLoopWithDelay(loopFn: any, delay: number) {
    let stamp = Date.now();

    // Added a new param `keepLoopFlg` but it's not changed when `StopLoop()` is called
    function _loop(keepLoopFlg: boolean) {
        if (keepLoopFlg && Date.now() - stamp >= delay) {
            loopFn();
            stamp = Date.now();
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(_loop.bind(this, this.isLoopOnFlg)); // Used `.bind(...)`
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(_loop.bind(this, this.isLoopOnFlg));
}
...
```

But the above code won't do what I want - when `StopLoop()` is called, the recursive function still keep going (memory leak).
I'd love to learn how to stop the recursive function with the current structure and to prevent memory leak.  Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not really recursive since it queues the callback on the event loop rather than calling the callback directly. So you don't have to worry about running out of memory on the call stack.

To stop calling requestAnimationFrame, you simply don't call it. The question is, when do you want to stop calling it? If you are providing a utility function for someone else, you usually let them dictate when to "unsubscribe" or stop the updates.

```
private recursiveLoopWithDelay(loopFn: any, delay: number) {
    const self = this;
    let stamp = Date.now();

    function _loop() {
        // If we aren't looping anymore, just exit the code.
        // Don't requeue requestAnimationFrame
        if (!self.isLoopOn) {
            return;
        }

        if (Date.now() - stamp >= delay) {
            loopFn();
            stamp = Date.now();
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(_loop);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(_loop);
}
```

You can also skip binding by using Lexical scope like I've done here. Storing `this` in a variable `self` that I can lookup at any point.

Comment: Ah gotya, the keys are `self = this` and the position of `isLoopOn`. Thanks for helping me out!